# MySQL COUNT return 0

Tags: mysql, count

As you can see here, `TotalPic` column return `0`. What's the problem?

```
SELECT P.*, U.*, COUNT(I.iid) AS TotalPic
FROM post P
LEFT JOIN users U ON U.uid = P.uid
LEFT JOIN images I ON I.pid = P.uid
WHERE P.pid = '2'
```

I tried to use `LEFT JOIN` like this thread solution [MYSQL COUNT return NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781240/mysql-count-return-null), but still the same.

```
+-----------+
|   images  |
+-----------+
| iid       |
| filename  |
| extension |
| pid       |
| uid       |
+-----------+

+-----------+
|   post    |
+-----------+
| pid       |
| uid       | 
|description|
| created_at|
+-----------+

+-----------+
|   users   |
+-----------+                
| uid   |
| fid       |
| date_reg  |
+-----------+
```

Comment: It returns 0 probably because you `WHERE P.pid = 2` eliminates matching rows.

Comment: Your `id` columns are a bit cryptic, but if the `p`s and `i`s and `u`s in the id names are significant, it would appear you are joining I and P on the wrong keys. It would be helpful if you provided the part of your DDL that defined the PK and FK columns.

Comment: You show zero information about your tables, zero data, and expect us to explain why `COUNT` returns zero? Please provide information on your schema (table definitions), and sample data from each table. Otherwise, your question is meaningless - you obviously have something wrong with it that's making it return no rows, but you provide nothing we can use to help you figure out why.

Comment: it's better if you try to learn more about sql/query

Comment: I have 3 rows in table `images` with `pid = 2`

Comment: @Jay: you also need rows in `post` and `users` with `pid=2`.

Comment: @JayHo: Can you provide some dummy data so we help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, thanks. I solved it by separating the query. I just need the counts and else doesn't matter.

```
$result = mysql_query("
          SELECT COUNT(iid) AS total_photo 
          FROM images WHERE pid = '$pid'");
```